# How to use variable value in all the functions in a same file using python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that requires user input and storing it in a variable. Now when I want to use this variable in other functions, I have to execute `input()` function first and hence again I have to provide the input.
Is it possible that I can use variable get_input in other functions also without executing `input()` function or providing the input again? I tried declaring the variable as `global` also but no use.

is it possible?

```
def input():
    get_input = str(input("please provide name"))
    return get_input

def output():
    val = input() # it is executing the function input() and hence need to prvoide input

def getvalue():
    val = input() # it is executing the function input() and hence need to provide input
```

can't we store value of input in one variable and use it in all the functions in a file?

`return` is making function to execute every time and hence input has to be provided everytime

Comment: define ```get_input``` outside the function and ```global get_input```  at top in every function

Comment: "can't we store value of input in one variable and use it in all the functions in a file?" -  Yes, you can. Just do it?

Comment: Note: do not name your functions after built-in Python functions (defining your own function `input`, and then using a built-in `input` within that function is really not a great idea)

Comment: `return is making function to execute every time`. This is not true. It is executed every time because it is called every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **global** variables here. You can take input outside all the functions and get the variable in the function using global function. Following is a sample code for your problem:-

```
get_input = str(input("please provide name"))

def a_input():
    global get_input
    print(get_input, "a")

def output():
    global get_input
    print(get_input, "b")

def getvalue():
    global get_input
    print(get_input, "c")
    
a_input()
output()
getvalue()
```

Following is the output of this code

```
please provide nameadeel
adeel a
adeel b
adeel c
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need globals. You can create a function which wraps the call to input and simply returns a cached value.

cachedinput.py *(defines function)*

```
from functools import partial, cache

getname = cache(partial(input, 'please provide name: '))
```

usecachedinput.py *(calls function)*

```
from cachedinput import getname

print(getname())
print(getname())
print(getname())
print(getname())
print(getname())
```

It will only ask for the name once. It could also export a variable rather than a function.

If the use of `functool.partial` here is a bit too cryptic. It can be implemented as a function with `cache` used as a decorator.

```
@cache
def getname2():
    return input('please provide name: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use global variables. However, I find that they can become very buggy when you use them. Another way would be to add parameters to the function. For example:

```py
def input():
    get_input = str(input("please provide name"))
    return get_input

my_input = input()

def output(my_input):
    val = my_input

def getvalue(my_input):
    val = my_input
```

Basically, first, you set a variable called `my_input` to the function `input()`. Then, you can just add `my_input` as a parameter for other functions. It might not be the most practical method, but it works fine.

However, please note that input is already a function in python, and it is not a good idea to make a function called input as it will cause errors and bugs.

Comment: `TypeError: input() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that's because Pilot Dude has an issue in his code. `input` is a builtin, but it's also defined in the first function definition. Therefore, python only sees the local definition before the regular definition. This would be fixed if he used a different name other than a builtin function.

Comment: @blackbrandt I know, thanks for the detailled explanation. That's why it's always good to test code before posting it as an answer! ;)

Comment: @blackbrandt yeah I know it was just that the user created the function as `input()` so I decided to leave it. I probably should've added a warning about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't define your first function as `input`. It will cause prblems because there is already a function named that. Assuming you call it something like `str_input`, one option would be to make `get_input` a global variable, something like so:

```py
get_input = None # set get_input to None so that you can tell of input has been asked for yet

def my_input():
    global get_input # make sure Python knows this is a global variable, not a local one
    get_input = input("please enter your name") # no need for str() here, input gives a string by default
    return get_input

def output():
     global get_input # make sure Python knows this is a global variable, not a local one
     if get_input is None: # we haven't asked for input yet
         val = my_input() # get some input
     else: # we have input already
        val = get_input # just get the original value

# the same for getvalue():

def getvalue():
     global get_input # make sure Python knows this is a global variable, not a local one
     if get_input is None: # we haven't asked for input yet
         val = my_input() # get some input
     else: # we have input already
        val = get_input # just get the original value
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're trying to make the function called Input modify the value of "get_input" correct? You're also trying to get the value in other methods as well. The way you would do this is by defining it outside of the method like this:

```
get_input=0

def Input():
    global get_input
    get_input = str(input("please provide name: "))
    return get_input

def output():
    global get_input
    val = get_input
    return val

def getvalue():
    global get_input
    val = get_input
    return val

test=Input()
print(test + "\t" + get_input + "\t" + getvalue() + "\t" + output())
```

Now if you provide for example "Hello World", the output in the sample code I posted will be "Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World" which is the value for get_input. Also input is a build-in method, so I've changed yours into "Input".

Comment: It's extremely poor practice to have two functions only differ by their capitalization (due to readability). I would recommend using a function name such as `my_input` or something like that.

Comment: I tried your approach and it is still giving me  get_input not defined error

Comment: @Enigmaderockz can you provide your code please?

Comment: @blackbrandt it's just for demonstration purposes.